# put value from one row to another scala dataaframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, row

I have one large dataframe with 222 columns I want to do like the following example

```
   |id        |day          |col1   |col2 | col3 ....................
+----------+----------------+-------+-----+
|       329|               0|   null|2.0
|       329|              42|   null|null
|       329|              72|   5.55|null
|       329|             106|   null|null
|       329|             135|   null|3.0
|       329|             168|   null|4.0
|       329|             189|  4.995|null
|       329|             212|   null|6.0
|       329|             247|   null|null
|       329|             274|   null|8.0



|id        |     day        |col1   |col2 |.......................
+----------+----------------+-------+-----+
|       329|               0|   null|2.0
|       329|              42|   null|2.0
|       329|              72|   5.55|2.0
|       329|             106|   5.55|2.0
|       329|             135|   5.55|3.0
|       329|             168|   5.55|4.0
|       329|             189|  4.995|4.0
|       329|             212|  4.995|6.0
|       329|             247|  4.995|6.0
|       329|             274|  4.995|8.0
.
.
.
.
.
```

1.read row 1 
2.i have 85k unique id's and for each id have 10 results(shown example of only one ID )
3.if in the row 2 data is not present the take it from ID's previous row

i got result like this

```
id         |    day         |original_col1 |Result_col1|prevValue|
+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|       329|               0|   null       |   null    |     null|
|       329|              42|   null       |   null    |     null|
|       329|              72|   5.55       |   5.55    |     null|
|       329|             106|   null       |   5.55    |     5.55|
|       329|             135|   null       |   null    |     null|
|       329|             168|   null       |   null    |     null|
|       329|             189|   4.995      |  4.995    |     null|
|       329|             212|   null       |  4.995    |    4.995|
|       330|....................................................
|       330|.....................................................
         .
```

Comment: is there a deterministic way for sorting the data to be able to use windowing functions (lag)? I understand you want to apply the logic above in a partition defined by col "id" but unless you have a way to define some ordering (assuming the order matters), in the case of partition with id "1", for "col1" you could end up with the null value in 1/2/3rd row and results are going to be different. If there's no ordering in the data you could try to use the monotonically_increasing_id() function to generate an order_id right after reading the data from file/source.

Comment: i forget add one column please check now, ID is unique and mandatory ID is nothing but user it and every ID have less than 6 records .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve that with existing windowing function (e.g. lag). You would need to use a similar concept for partitioning and sorting but with custom logic for rolling the not null values.

```
case class MyRec(id: Integer, day: Integer, col1: Option[Double], col2: Option[Double])

defined class MyRec

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val ds = Seq(
  MyRec(329, 0, None, Some(2.0)),
  MyRec(329, 42, None, None),
  MyRec(329, 72, Some(5.55), None),
  MyRec(329, 106, None, None),
  MyRec(329, 135, None, Some(3.0)),
  MyRec(329, 168, None, Some(4.0)),
  MyRec(329, 189, Some(4.995), None),
  MyRec(329, 212, None, Some(6.0)),
  MyRec(329, 247, None, None),
  MyRec(329, 274, None, Some(8.0))
).toDS()

ds.printSchema()
ds.show(false)

val updated_ds = ds.repartition('id).sortWithinPartitions('id, 'day)
  .mapPartitions(iter => {
    var crtId: Integer = null
    var prevId: Integer = null
    var rollingVals = collection.mutable.Map[String, Option[Double]]()
    for (rec <- iter) yield {
      crtId = rec.id

      // 1st record for new id
      if (prevId == null || crtId != prevId) {
        rollingVals = collection.mutable.Map[String, Option[Double]]()
        prevId = crtId
      }

      rollingVals("col1") = if (rec.col1.isDefined) rec.col1 else rollingVals.getOrElse("col1", None)
      rollingVals("col2") = if (rec.col2.isDefined) rec.col2 else rollingVals.getOrElse("col2", None)
      MyRec(rec.id, rec.day, rollingVals("col1"), rollingVals("col2"))
    }
  })

updated_ds.printSchema()
updated_ds.show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = true)

+---+---+-----+----+
|id |day|col1 |col2|
+---+---+-----+----+
|329|0  |null |2.0 |
|329|42 |null |null|
|329|72 |5.55 |null|
|329|106|null |null|
|329|135|null |3.0 |
|329|168|null |4.0 |
|329|189|4.995|null|
|329|212|null |6.0 |
|329|247|null |null|
|329|274|null |8.0 |
+---+---+-----+----+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = true)

+---+---+-----+----+
|id |day|col1 |col2|
+---+---+-----+----+
|329|0  |null |2.0 |
|329|42 |null |2.0 |
|329|72 |5.55 |2.0 |
|329|106|5.55 |2.0 |
|329|135|5.55 |3.0 |
|329|168|5.55 |4.0 |
|329|189|4.995|4.0 |
|329|212|4.995|6.0 |
|329|247|4.995|6.0 |
|329|274|4.995|8.0 |
+---+---+-----+----+

ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyRec] = [id: int, day: int ... 2 more fields]
updated_ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyRec] = [id: int, day: int ... 2 more fields]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window function and then case-when:

```
val df2 = df
   .withColumn("prevValue", lag('col1, 1).over(Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('day)))
    .withColumn("col1", when('col1.isNull, 'prevValue).otherwise('col1))
```

Import also spark.implicits._

Comment: i'm new so please understand may it is easy  error: overloaded method value lag with alternatives:
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (columnName: String,offset: Int,defaultValue: Any)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (columnName: String,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to (String)

Comment: @RahulNirdhar Sorry, I forgot about one argument. Now it should work :)

Comment: thank you, but it's not working as  I want, it  gives the wrong result please see result in question

Comment: @RahulNirdhar Ok now I changed columns :)

Comment: @ T. Gawęda I did that by myself but not working got result like above

Comment: T. Gawęda Thank you